# How to show $N$ is a manifold of dimension 3

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Take $N$ = $(\mathbb{R}^{4}$ \ $GL(2,\mathbb{R}))$ \ $\{0\}$

Thus far, I know that $ GL(2,\mathbb{R}) $ is a 4 dimensional manifold conceived as an open set of $\mathbb{R^{4}} \cong M(2,R)$. To show this I used the usual argument of taking the determinant functions continuity and the topological definition of continuity to show that $GL(2,\mathbb{R}) \cong det^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^{4}}$, and as such inducing the ambient smooth manifold structure of $\mathbb{R^{4}}$ onto the open set.

My inkling is that we can treat $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ as the set of all transformations which yield some nonzero scaling factor, or in other words all transformations which admit non-zero volume to some hyperparallelepiped. If we strip away all such objects from $\mathbb{R^{4}}$ then we are left with all objects in $\mathbb{R^{4}}$ which do not admit volume, which as I see it should be $k$-dimension hypersurfaces with $k \leq 3$. This is how I intuitively attain the dimension of the manifold, of course under the supposition that this could all be fallacious reasoning. This, however, does not allude to me someway of generating an appropriate atlas.

So with my preamble complete, the crux of my inquiry is this;

How can I generate a differentiable atlas for this space $(\mathbb{R}^{4}$ \ $GL(2,\mathbb{R}))$ \ $\{0\}$ which is a 3 dimensional manifold?

Comment: What does `A \ B \ C` mean, please? Normally I think that `A \ B` means $A - (A \cap B)$, i.e., elements of $A$ not in $B$. But I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: \ means set complement or simply minus. So I mean to say; take $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ from $\mathbb{R^{4}}$ and then take the zero element from that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be addressed by an application of the implicit function theorem, using the function $f: \Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R : \pmatrix { a\\b\\c\\d} \mapsto ad-bc$. The set $N$ is precisely the zero-set of $f$, except for the vector $\pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0}$. At all other points of the domain (i.e., at all points of $N$) the jacobian of $f$, namely
$$
Jf(\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d}) = \pmatrix{d\\-c\\-b\\a}
$$
has rank 1, because at least one of $a,b,c,d$ is nonzero. That lets you conclude (by the theorem) that in a neighborhood of that point, the zero set is diffeomorphic to an open disk in 3-space, hence that $N$ is a 3-manifold.